# How can I reuse a piece of code to edit multiple pictureboxes

Tags: c#, edit, picturebox, reusability

Im trying to write a piece of code to set the image of the 92 pictureboxes I have in my form. I don´t want to write the same piece of code 92 times, so i was wondering if this can be done faster. My code is:

```
public void drawRoute()
{
    if (route1.line_00_R == null)
    {
        this.tabMap.Controls.Remove(this.line_00_R);
    }
    else if (route1.line_00_R == "Blue")
    {
        this.tabMap.Controls.Add(this.line_00_R);
        this.line_00_R.Image = global::MijnenvegerController.Properties.Resources.Blue;
    }
    else if (route1.line_00_R == "Red")
    {
        this.tabMap.Controls.Add(this.line_00_R);
        this.line_00_R.Image = global::MijnenvegerController.Properties.Resources.Red;
    }
}
```

I hope something like this is possible:

```
public void drawRoute()
{
    for (//all values of {0})
    {
        if (route1.{0} == null)
        {
            this.tabMap.Controls.Remove(this.{0});
        }
        else
        {
            {1} = route1.{0}; // string that is the same as the name of the resource
            this.tabMap.Controls.Add(this.{0});
            this.{0}.Image = global::MijnenvegerController.Properties.Resources.{1};
        }
    }
}
```

where {0} and {1} are some kind of placeholders or variables.

Hope someone can help me. I only started with C# this week, so I hpe this is not a stupid question. Thanks in advance for all help!

EDIT

I found something I think I can use, but I dont know how to implement it:

`public Control[] Find(
    string key,
    bool searchAllChildren
)`

[Control.ControlCollection.Find Method (http://msdn.microsoft.com)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find.aspx)

I realise I can do it like that now. But I already made all the different PictureBoxes using the Disigner. I 'solved' in a very dirty way using this code now:

`
public void drawRoute()
        {
            drawRoad(route1.line_00_R, this.line_00_R);
            drawRoad(route1.line_00_U, this.line_00_U);
            drawRoad(route1.line_01_D, this.line_01_D);
            drawRoad(route1.line_01_R, this.line_01_R);

// etc. etc. 92 times!

```
        drawRoad(route1.line_6, this.line_6);
        drawRoad(route1.line_7, this.line_7);
        drawRoad(route1.line_8, this.line_8);
        drawRoad(route1.line_9, this.line_9);
        drawRoad(route1.line_10, this.line_10);
        drawRoad(route1.line_11, this.line_11);
        drawRoad(route1.line_12, this.line_12);
    }

    public void drawRoad(string color, PictureBox control)
    {
        if (color == null)
        {
            this.tabMap.Controls.Remove(control);
        }
        else if (color.Equals("Blue"))
        {
            this.tabMap.Controls.Add(control);
            control.Image = global::MijnenvegerController.Properties.Resources.Blue;
        }
        else if (color.Equals("DarkRed"))
        {
            this.tabMap.Controls.Add(control);
            control.Image = global::MijnenvegerController.Properties.Resources.DarkRed;
        }
        else if (color.Equals("Indigo"))
        {
            this.tabMap.Controls.Add(control);
            control.Image = global::MijnenvegerController.Properties.Resources.Indigo;
        }
        else if (color.Equals("GreyBlue"))
        {
            this.tabMap.Controls.Add(control);
            control.Image = global::MijnenvegerController.Properties.Resources.GreyBlue;
        }
        else if (color.Equals("Gold"))
        {
            this.tabMap.Controls.Add(control);
            control.Image = global::MijnenvegerController.Properties.Resources.Gold;
        }
        else if (color.Equals("Orange"))
        {
            this.tabMap.Controls.Add(control);
            control.Image = global::MijnenvegerController.Properties.Resources.Orange;
        }
    }
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to solve this is by adding the pictureboxes to a 2 dimensional array so you can use a nested loop to loop through the controls/map:

```
private PictureBox[,] _cell = new PictureBox[9,10];
```

In the form load you could add all the PictureBoxes to the array. So you can access them like this:

```
for(int row = 0; row < 10; row++)
{
    for(int column=0; column < 9; column++)
    {
        // drawing logic for _cell[column, row]
    }
}
```

Does that make sense? Do you need more help?

Comment: If you are learning it might be better to restructure than to go the dirty way. In the end it will save you a lot of work.

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful, but I'm studying Electrical Engeneering, and this is just to make a wireless controle interface for the mine detection robot we're making. We're supposed to controle it from command line (in C) but I want to make it a bit better. Learning C# is not the main objective.

Thanks for your help.

Erik